# Created a button in Android and want to keep track of clicks but click count isn't being recorded correctly

Tags: java, android, for-loop, event-listener

EDIT: Just fixing up my old questions and I can see the problem younger me had. It would be clicked once and it would run through the whole loop.

I wanted to create a button and keep track of the number of clicks with a for loop.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //Connects the button by ID and reference to the design button
    Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    //When the button is clicked it will display the amount of times the button is clicked
    button.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    TextView text= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
                    for(int i = 0;i < 20;++i) {
                        String s = Integer.toString(i);

                        text.setText(s);
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

When I run it and click the button once it automatically goes to 19 rather than start at 0.

Comment: it's because it go through your loop, and your loop finish when i < 20 (and that is 19).

Comment: I wonder why u using loop if you have to count number of click on button clicl event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The onClick method is called once every time the button is clicked. You have a for loop in there counting up to 19 so every time the button is clicked you are rapidly setting the text again with the numbers 1-19 until it reaches 19.

If you want to keep a seperate counter you can make a global variable then increment it by one in the onClick method. This should provide the desired behaviour:

```
private int count = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //Connects the button by ID and reference to the design button
    Button andrewsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.andrewsButton);

    //When the button is clicked it will display the amount of times the button is clicked
    andrewsButton.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    TextView andrewsText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.andrewsText);
                    count++;
                    andrewsText.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks but I should have said it was in an @override method because using the private count inside of it would cause an error but once I moved it inside the oncreate method i could use your code but with a few changes which were: final int[] count = {0};
andrewsButton[0].setOnClickListener(
count[0]++;
andrewsText.setText(String.valueOf(count[0]));
... these changes offered by Android Studio to fix the code allowed it to worth

Comment: It shouldn't matter if it's an @Override method.

Comment: well it asked me to put it in a one element array to make it work

Comment: It sounds like something weird is going on. You can try doing some research on it then post another question of you don't find anything. I don't think the issue is related to this question though.